# Issue with net-snmp build on Solaris 11

Tags: solaris, net-snmp

I am building net-snmp 5.7.3 on Solaris11 sparc. I am having my path set as:

/usr/local/lib:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/dev_infra/platform/bin:/usr/dev_infra/generic/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/local/ade/bin:/usr/sfw/bin:/usr/ccs/bin:/opt/csw/bin:/opt/csw/gnu:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/ccs/bin/ar

I run  ./configure --prefix=/opt with default option and it was successful. After that when i do make, i am getting below error message, Any help is appreciated.

```
libtool: compile:  gcc -I../include -I. -I../snmplib -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -Usolaris2 -Dsolaris2=solaris2 -c keytools.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/keytools.o
keytools.c: In function ‘generate_Ku’:
keytools.c:153:9: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
keytools.c:161:9: error: invalid use of void expression
keytools.c:166:13: error: invalid use of void expression
*** Error code 1
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `keytools.lo'
Current working directory /scratch/kkumsati/net-snmp/snmplib
*** Error code 1
The following command caused the error:
if test "snmplib  agent apps man local mibs" != ""; then \
        it="snmplib  agent apps man local mibs" ; \
        for i in $it ; do \
                echo "making all in `pwd`/$i"; \
                ( cd $i ; make ) ; \
                if test $? != 0 ; then \
                        exit 1 ; \
                fi  \
        done \
fi
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `subdirs'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for **README.solaris** file in source folder. It has 'Compiling net-snmp' section.
In README you could find the following:

```
You need to set your $PATH.  This is extremely important
because otherwise there may be conflicts between the various
components of the development environment.
```

**Wrong PATH is your problem.**

The other possible problem are old openssl headers in your system. 
You have an error about function **EVP_MD_CTX_create()** (error in keytools.c:153:9), this function is declared in Solaris file /usr/include/openssl/evp.h, this file is included in package pkg:/library/security/openssl. Version of this package on my OS is 1.0.1.18-0.175.3.5.0.5.0.
I recommend you to update OS, or package pkg:/library/security/openssl or try to run configure script with `--with-openssl=internal` option.

Also update gcc, I used this version

```
pkg install developer/gcc-48 

export PATH=/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/ccs/bin:/usr/bin:
./configure --prefix=/opt --with-mib-modules="ucd-snmp/lmSensors \
            ucd-snmp/diskio smux mibII/mta_sendmail" --with-cc=gcc
gmake
```

Here I received an error about:

```
/usr/include/sys/processor.h:188:45: error: unknown type name 'kthread_t'
 extern boolean_t i_processor_affinity_check(kthread_t *, struct cpu *);
                                         ^
/usr/include/sys/processor.h:189:37: error: unknown type name 'kthread_t'
 extern int i_processor_affinity_one(kthread_t *, id_t, boolean_t);
                                 ^
/usr/include/sys/processor.h:190:33: error: unknown type name 'kthread_t'
 extern int i_processor_affinity(kthread_t *, uint_t *, id_t *, uint32_t *,
                             ^
```

To solve this edit file  `agent/mibgroup/host/data_access/swrun_procfs_psinfo.c` and add to its header **at 26 line** (before problem line):

```
#include <sys/processor.h>
#include <sys/procset.h>
#include <thread.h>
```

Link about this [bug](https://sourceforge.net/p/net-snmp/bugs/2639/)

then repeat

```
gmake
gmake test
gmake install;  #this command with root permissons
```

I succeed on SPARC.

Comment: My path:     -bash-4.1$ echo $PATH
/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/ccs/bin:/usr/bin
GCC version i am using is gcc version 4.5.2 (GCC)
./configure command is successful but make giving error:
keytools.c: In function ‘generate_Ku’:
keytools.c:153:9: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
keytools.c:161:9: error: invalid use of void expression
keytools.c:166:13: error: invalid use of void expression
make[1]: *** [keytools.lo] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/scratch/kkumsati/net-snmp/snmplib'
make: *** [subdirs] Error 1

Comment: uname -a o/p : SunOS blr222  5.11 11.1 sun4v sparc sun4v

Comment: Dear @skm_satish, could you update your OS to actual version? May be it is the problem. System on which I receieved this result in newer. pkg list entire shows 0.5.11-0.175.3.6.0.5.0 (it is 11.3.6). But you have 11.1.

Comment: I investigated your error about EVP_MD_CTX_create()  (located in keytools.c:153:9), this function is declared in Solaris file /usr/include/openssl/evp.h. This file is included in package pkg:/library/security/openssl. Version of this package on my OS is 1.0.1.18-0.175.3.5.0.5.0. If you have troubles with updating whole system, try to start update with pkg:/library/security/openssl.

Comment: Also you could try to run configure script with `--with-openssl=internal` option to skip system openssl headers.

Comment: Thank a lot Shasha for all the inputs. I was able to build after changing configure command to                                                                                                                                ./configure --prefix=/opt --with-mib-modules="ucd-snmp/lmSensors       ucd-snmp/diskio smux mibII/mta_sendmail" --with-cc=gcc --with-openssl=internal

Comment: Hi @sasha golikov ..i am facing issue for solaris10x86..can you please help.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51017733/issue-with-snmp-install-on-solaris10x86   thanks in advance